# "GRANT SELECT table TO role" is not working

Tags: postgresql

I have very simple db (PostgreSQL)

And i created one role: `manage`

command: `CREATE ROLE manage WITH NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB LOGIN;`

Then, I executed

```
set role postgres;
GRANT SELECT ON public.orders TO manage;
SET ROLE manage;
SELECT * FROM orders;
```

But, when I try to execute:

```
select * from orders
```

I see empty output

[image: output - role:manage]

But, in that table, there are some rows:

Here is the output using the role postgres.

[image: output - role:postgres]

I want give right to read to "manage" role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. There are two tables with the same name in different schemas
2. Row level security is active on the table.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! 2 way is working!

But, i don't understand, why

Comment: Because somebody enabled it? I don't know your system, and you don't give much information, so I am restricted to enumerating possible explanations for the observed behavior.

Comment: Yes!! I enabled it.